# Alamofire 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

When I am trying to server request in my swift code block, some errors occured after server response JSON like the code below;

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Utility.WebServiceAddress+"/ApproveOrder", parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON
    {(request, response, JSON, error) in

        if let jsonResult: NSDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let wsResult = jsonResult[WSConstants.WSRESULT] as? NSDictionary
            {
                let resultCode = wsResult.valueForKey(WSConstants.RESULT_CODE) as Int
                if(resultCode == Utility.WS_RESULT_SUCCESS)
                {
                    self.PrepareMainItemsInBagToSetUpLocalNotifications()
                    Utility.ActivityIndicatorStopAnimating(self.activityIndicator, indicatorLabel: self.lblIndicatorMessage, viewController: self)
                    Utility.ReleaseBagAndPopToInitialViewController(self)
                }
                else
                {
                    PromptDialogs.getPromptDialogWebServiceError(self.activityIndicator, lblIndicatorMessage: self.lblIndicatorMessage, viewController: self, message: "Sipariş tablebiniz gönderilirken hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz!")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PromptDialogs.getPromptDialogWebServiceError(self.activityIndicator, lblIndicatorMessage: self.lblIndicatorMessage, viewController: self, message: "Sunucudan yanıt alınamadı. Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrol edip yeniden deneyiniz!")
        }
    } // gives 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' at this line, as refering Alamofire code below -> 

public func responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(serializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: options), completionHandler: { (request, response, JSON, error) in
        completionHandler(request, response, JSON, error)
    })
}
```

I used this request way for some other UIViewControllers. But I did not understand that why am I getting this error only here? If it is necessary for you, I can share the more detailed code block.

Could you help me ?

Best regards

Comment: You are getting this error because something is become nil at runtime so do some debugging and test your code and you will find that surely.

Comment: I get the result as "wsresultCode, wsResult and wsresultMessage" all the time. When I debugged, I saw that "wsresultCode = 1, wsresult = null, wsresultMessage = null". I have suspicion that the error occures due to "wsresult = null".

Comment: I have also got the similar issue, did you able to solve this issue?